# French characters not being displayed properly

Tags: php, json, curl

I am using curl to pull in a news feed, however the french version is pulling in some weird characters.

For example "activitÃ©s" should be "activités"

```
$feed = curl_init($json);
$options = array(
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
   CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json'),
   CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $feed
);
curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
$news = curl_exec($feed);
curl_close($feed);

$articles = json_decode($news, true);
```

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/), [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: You need to get your encoding handling in line. The browser is interpreting the content in the wrong encoding, plain and simple. Read all the above.

Comment: @deceze, you could have mentioned. check my profile instead of putting up all those links.

Comment: @Shankar The advantage of which is...?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to set the correct charset, i.e. `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json', 'charset=utf-8')`

This could probably solve your problem.